# Are "workflow" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29300685/4200092) today:

> ### Love Mercurial and hate Git but have to open-source on GitHub
>
> Is there any workflow to allow me to work with Mercurial and BitBucket
>   comfortably but still make it available to GitHub users in an easy
>   way?
>
> PS: I strongly prefer GUI to command line.

...and I'm not sure if it's on topic or not. It's clearly about ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (thus making it on-topic) but at the same time it's not a *direct* "How do I do `$x` with `$vcs_or_ide_y`?" question either. In fact, based on [a link given in one of the comments](http://hg-git.github.io/), it could be argued that it's a recommendation request in disguise.

It seems like a bit of a grey area to me. Is this a "tool" question, or a "workflow" one, and is it considered "on-topic"?

Comment: I don't see how it's a recommendation question.  Depending on how involved it is (I have no idea what accomplishing this would entail) I could possibly see it being Too Broad (if it would require some involved construction, and not say just a simple configuration work.

Comment: I edited the title. To me this was the **only** objectionable aspect of the post. I hope it gets a complete and proper answer.

Comment: The minor changes to the question were an effort to remove personalization.

Comment: Please also note I have no preference between Mercurial and Git. I just think that this question has community value, even if it is in a grey area. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/03/podcast-63-the-plumbers-up-to-67-coins/

Comment: I notice that the post in question has now been [put on hold](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29300685/4200092).

Answer (score 4):

Even asking about workflow can be okay, and especially if there are many users having a common problem and could benefit from a good answer this could really make sense on a Q&A website, I'd say workflow questions are also easy to ask and to turn ones (often subjective) problem description in a question fishing for help.

There's nothing wrong with help, but if the help couldn't be put in the general format, that's not so well then.

The question is clearly subjective. It's "Me" "comfortably" "in an easy way" which sounds a bit like someone wants to use something not intended for it but still get the sugar blown in. In my opinion this is asking for an off-site-resource. The question would be better fitted on the github Q&A or in the support section of mercurial where it's talked about public hosting serivces.

Comment: So, would you consider [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29555947/4200092) to be a good fit for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, tool recommendations are off-topic, so in order to ask such a question you would have to state in advance which tools that are used and ask for a better way to use them.

Second, any question which is of the nature *"what is the best..."*, or *"can we discuss ways of doing..."* is also off-topic, as it will yield opinion-based answers.

The best way to ask such a question would therefore be to state which tools that are used and then what problem you are facing when using them. A question like

*"I'm using Eclipse version <...> with compiler <...>. My project setup is <....> and it is very burdensome to do <...> in this project. How could I improve this?"*

would be perfectly fine. It is specific and doesn't involve tool recommendations.

Comment: "*would be perfectly fine*" Well... arguably too broad. It could be improved in any of a million ways.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett It would be a specific problem such as "the build time is too long" or "I'm facing these problems when integrating my version control system with this" etc etc.

Comment: "*How can I improve my code?*" is off-topic so why would "*how can I improve my workflow?*" be on-topic?

Comment: @TinyGiant What makes you think code improvement questions are off-topic? Just because the Code review site might be more suitable doesn't make it off-topic on SO. In fact, SO has not changed the definition of what's on-topic since before the Code review site was born, so SO is essentially a super-set of Code review. If you think this is stupid, start a separate meta discussion about it and demand that code review questions should be off-topic. Until that happens, don't go label code improvement off-topic.